# How to use more generalized lables when using Caffe for classification

Tags: neural-network, classification, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am using a pre-trained AlexNet in Caffe for classification. However, the output from classification is around 1000 classes from the `'synset_words.txt'` file. Is there a way to use more generic classes?

For example instead of having as output the type of dog in the picture, i just want the output to be "dog".

I know that there's a hierarchy in the classes, but is there a way to retrieve that hierarchy and use it to get more generic labels?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [image-net API documentation](http://image-net.org/download-API):

> **WordNet Hierarchy**
>   The [following file](http://www.image-net.org/archive/wordnet.is_a.txt) provides all "is-a" relations provided by WordNet 3.0. Each line is a parent-child pair.

You need to download the `'wordnet.ia_a.txt'` file, parse it and build the wordnet hierarchy.